# jquery remove specific element from a specific id

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div like this:

```
<div id="container1"><input class="1"><input class="2"></div>

<div id="container2"><input class="1"><input class="1"><input class="2"></div>
```

Now how do I remove all class="1" but only from the container2.

Comment: I've noticed that none of your input tags is closed, should be `<input class="1" />`

Comment: @Nick: `<input>` is fine if you don't need to validate for XHTML.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it.

`$('#container2 .1').remove();`

This seeks all descendants from the element with id "container2" which belongs to the class named "1" and then remove them from the DOM.

Comment: My suggestion:  `$('#container2 input.1').remove()`. Maybe things have changed but I believe that in the case of class selectors adding a tag improves performance.

Comment: +1, but note that this makes the assumption that you want to remove class=1 elements _and all of their children_.

Comment: Technically, he said "remove all class="1"" and not just input elements, though in his example they are the same. I'm also not sure  if descendant selectors can be optimized the same way. But in general I agree with you.

Comment: "and all of their children" - I usually operate with the assumption that removing an element implies removing its children too, since to not do so could have very strange consequences in most situations.